# Initramfs creating bad/duplicate mount point in Linux

Tags: linux, centos-7, initrd, initramfs-tools, dracut

I have a CentOS7 system, and I built a 4.14.29 kernel for it, created an initrd for it - just as I have many, many other times. When I now do this (going from a 4.11 to a 4.14.29 kernel) - I am seeing my root filesystem *also* getting mounted over `/usr`. It *only* happens with the 4.14 kernel, though I susspect that it is the actual *initramfs* that is doing it.

During initrd - I see:

```
[  OK  ] Reached target Remote File Systems.
         Mounting /sysroot...
[  OK  ] Mounted /sysroot.
         Mounting /sysroot/usr...
[  OK  ] Mounted /sysroot/usr.
[  OK  ] Reached target Initrd Root File System.
         Starting Reload Configuration from the Real Root...
[  OK  ] Started Reload Configuration from the Real Root.
[  OK  ] Reached target Initrd File Systems.
```

There should only be a "root" filesystem. There is nothing that is supposed to mount at `/usr`, and certainly nothing in /etc/fstab that should make it do so. So I don't know why it would be mounting a `/sysroot/usr`. I even explicitly removed the `usrmount` dracut module - no difference.

Furhermore, it should't be re-mounting the "root" filesystem here. The root filesystem is a /dev/mapper LVM device.

Any idea what would cause this, and how to fix it? (P.S. I cannot get int Dracut emergency shell for some odd reason...)

Comment: 2.11? 2.14.29? Those kernel versions never existed – it went from 2.6.39 to 3.0. Did you mean 4.11 and 4.14.29?

Comment: Sorry - I meant "4.11" and "4.14.29".